# How to un-install sql server 2008 analysis service only?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Initally I installed SQL server 2008 R2 Evaluation version. Then we bought licence key for SQL server 2008 R2 Web and wanted to update my licence, but unfortunately I installed analysis service when I was installing evaluation version which is not there in Web version so now I have to un-install analysis service. I googled this thing but found no real help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To remove an instance of SQL Server Analysis Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143687%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

1. On the Microsoft Windows desktop click **Start**, click **Control Panel**, and then double-click **Add or Remove Programs**.
2. Under **Currently installed programs**, select **Microsoft SQL Server**, and then click **Change**. This will start the **Microsoft SQL Server Maintenance Wizard**.

   **Note:** If you click **Remove** instead of **Change**, you will not be able to uninstall an instance of Analysis Services without also uninstalling the **SQL Server Database Engine** and **Reporting Services** installed under the same instance name.
3. On the **Component Selection** page, under **SQL Server instances**, select the instance that includes the instance of Analysis Services that you want to remove.
4. On the **Feature Maintenance** page, select Analysis Services. The **Microsoft SQL Server Maintenance Wizard** then launches the **Microsoft SQL Server Installation Wizard**.
5. On the **Change or Remove Instance** page, click **Remove Microsoft SQL Server**.
6. Click **Next**, and then follow the instructions on subsequent wizard pages.

Comment: Thanks Karan. I posted on another site as well and someone gave me same info.